# Is there such a concept as „encrypted operations“ on cyphertext?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Homomorphic encryption allows computation of (arithmetic or boolean) operations on ciphertext with the result being another ciphertext.

In that case...

- client `A` encrypts `p_in`
- `A` sends encrypted data `c_in` to the computer `C`
- `C` performs a set of known (from perspective of `C`) operations `f_p(c_in) = c_out`
- `A` is able to decrypt `c_out` to `p_out`
- due to the homomorphic property `f_p(c_in) = c_out => f_p(p_in) = p_out`

Is there a concept that would allow **computation of "encrypted" operations on ciphertext**?

- client `A` encrypts `p_in` to `c_in` and `f_p` to `f_c`
- `A` sends encrypted data `c_in` and encrypted operations `f_c` to the computer `C`
- `C` performs a set of (semantically) unknown (from perspective of `C`) operations `f_c(c_in)`
- now from here there are two options:

  1. `f_c(c_in) = c_out`: the result is a ciphertext as well
  2. `f_c(c_in) = p_out`: the result is a plaintext

While **1.** is a strict "enhancement" to homomorphic encryption, **2.** has different implications and limitations.

- the encrypted operations `ENC_f(f_p, s) = f_c` should not be (too) dependent on `p_in` or `c_in`

  - instead `ENC_f(f_p, s) = f_c` and `ENC_p(p_in, s) = c_in` should (somehow) have a shared secret `s`
  - the whole concept becomes less useful the more conditions for `p_in` / `c_in` are in `f_c`
- the plaintext result of `f_c(c_in)`is known to `C` so `f_c` should not reveal too much about its input, e.g.

  - if `f_c` would be a SUM or AVG function it could be abused by `C` to find out more about other `c* =/= c_in`
  - on the other hand if `f_c` is something like `f_c(c_in) = p_in < 1300` since the only output is either `true` or `false` and neither (semantics of the) operation nor (semantics of the) input is known to `C` there seems to be no issue with `C` obtaining more information that they should

Is there any concept known with any type of operations (logic gates...) that would allow for such an application (either **1.** or **2.**)? Or is it maybe proven that such a concept can or cannot exist?

Comment: A must read [Can any one explain Circuit Privacy using fully homomorphic encryption from Gentry's thesis?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8683/18298),  and a duplicate of [Does homomorphic encryption hide the algorithm itself?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/75941/18298)

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of those concepts.

Comment: @Dejan Please respond to the last request. If it does fully answer your question then please indicate that. Otherwise please comment on why it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That does indeed answer my question.